# How to show one value for all days of month in obiee?

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

It might seem strange but I have a requirement to show one value for all days of a month.

In database, there are records only for the first day of months. When I create analysis in BI with day prompt, obviously I get null values for every day except the first day of a month. How can I fix this measere(value in 01.01.2018, 01.02.2018 etc.) for all days? Of course when months changes column should present the value of first day of the next month. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the aggregation rule to FIRST for the meaasure on the Time dimension, level Month, and to SUM for all others.

Comment: I set the date column of fact table to FIRST, then table source level to MONTH. My Calendar dimension table has level set to DAY so it shows warning in consistency check, after uploading rpd measures became null. All other measures are set to SUM. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Would such a query do any good?

`the_whole_month` CTE creates all days in each month; table function call is here to to avoid duplicates

```
SQL> with test (first_day, value) as
  2    (select date '2018-01-01', 100 from dual union all
  3     select date '2018-02-01', 200 from dual union all
  4     select date '2018-03-01', 300 from dual
  5    ),
  6  the_whole_month as
  7    (select (first_day + column_value - 1) datum, value
  8     from test,
  9          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                              connect by level <= last_day(first_day) - first_day + 1
 11                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  select * from the_whole_month
 14  order by datum;

DATUM         VALUE
-------- ----------
01.01.18        100         -- January begins here
02.01.18        100
<snip>
29.01.18        100
30.01.18        100
31.01.18        100
01.02.18        200         -- February begins here
02.02.18        200
<snip>
27.02.18        200
28.02.18        200
01.03.18        300         -- March begins here
02.03.18        300
<snip>
29.03.18        300
30.03.18        300
31.03.18        300

90 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Regarding duplicates (you'd get without the table function): query would look like this; I shortened those months to only 3 days each. You'd expect 3 monts x 3 days = 9 rows, but you'll get 39 rows. If you're patient enough to run it for the whole month, and for all months you have, you might get ... I don't know, *millions* of rows. Don't do that.

```
SQL> with test (first_day, value) as
  2    (select date '2018-01-01', 100 from dual union all
  3     select date '2018-02-01', 200 from dual union all
  4     select date '2018-03-01', 300 from dual
  5    ),
  6  the_whole_month as
  7    (select (first_day + level - 1) datum, value
  8     from test
  9     connect by level <= 3  --> Presuming there are only 3 days in every month.
 10                            --> You'd expect 3 x 3 = 9 rows, but you'll get 39.
 11    )
 12  select * from the_whole_month
 13  order by datum;

DATUM         VALUE
-------- ----------
01.01.18        100
02.01.18        100
02.01.18        100
02.01.18        100
03.01.18        100
03.01.18        100
03.01.18        100
<snip>  
03.03.18        300
03.03.18        300

39 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I am looking for. So what you are suggesting is to insert your query results into my table using corresponding values , right? That seems a good way, but is there any option to do that without changing the table contents? Maybe in BI or rpd?

Comment: You're welcome. My CTE is here just to "simulate" your table, which already contains data about first-days-in-monts. I don't have it, so I fabricated one. You need code from line 6 onwards, substituting TEST with actual table name. Additional adjustments might be needed, though, but yes - that's the general idea. P.S. I don't use BI nor "rpd" (whatever it is), so I can't comment that.

Comment: Your question is quite vague to begin with - especially in the context of OBIEE. What are you trying to achieve? Can you explain it any different?

Comment: @Chris, what I mean is there are two measures F1 and F2, F1 is has values only for the first day of the month, F2 is has for every day. What I want is, in analysis, I use both measures to show both F1 and F2 for selected day and the month of that day (which is from F1 and has values only for 1st days). Since F1 has no values for other days when we select date like 02.09.2018 it has null values while F2 has its own. I want F1 to show value for 01.09.2018 even for other days of September.

Comment: @Littlefoot, thank you, I got the point. It was really helpful

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.